# react same keys pushed into a table row depending on user Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So i'm getting my data from an API which returns this:

```
appointments: [0: {customerId: 1, customerName: john, serviceName: serviceName1, start: {dateTime:"15:00"}, end: {dateTime:"16:00"}},
1: {customerId: 2, customerName: doe, serviceName: serviceName2, start: {dateTime:"14:00"}, end: {dateTime:"15:00"}},
2: {customerId: 2, customerName: doe,serviceName: serviceName3 , start: {dateTime:"12:00"}, end: {dateTime:"13:00"}}]
```

my snippet of code

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">room</th>
          <th scope="col">customer name</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName1</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName 2</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName 3</th>
          <th scope="col">other</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.appointments.map((appointments: any, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={appointments.customerId}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <td>{appointments.customerName}</td>
              {}
              <td>{`${formatDateTime(
                appointments.start?.dateTime
              )} - ${formatDateTime(appointments.end?.dateTime)}`}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
```

My question is how can i push depending on the customer Id his both services (serviceName 2, and serviceName 3) into the same row and each row fills in the appropraite header the time for each service?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If `appointments.customerId` alone doesn't provide the uniqueness guarantee that React keys need, then try a combination of properties that do, and if that still doesn't work then preprocess your `appointments` state to include a new GUID `id` property that you ***can*** guarantee is unique.

Comment: Well it does return uniqueness but if it is the same customer then it returns both with the same ID. But the thing is i need to check that if both have same ID, in other words same customerName then push the data into same row with each value into the appropriate header

Comment: True, but after squashing all the entries of one customer into one row, the id will be unique.

Comment: Ah, so you want to combine *some* data entires into a single row if they belong to the same customer. Can you share what the merged row would/should look like? Joined array of start/end dateTimes?

Comment: @DrewReese Exactly! i uploaded the photo in the main question

Comment: @henk yes they will be unique but thats not what i'm looking for. im kind of stumbled of how to push data into same row depending on each customer Id. Like drew said is exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: I understood your question, give me some time and I will provide an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preprocess your data to reduce the duplicates into single entries to map in your UI. Merge the services and times into a nested array to map into additional services columns.

```
Object.values(
  data.reduce(
    (dataObj, current) => ({
      ...dataObj,
      [current.customerId]: {
        ...dataObj[current.customerId],
        customerId: current.customerId,
        customerName: current.customerName,
        services: (dataObj[current.customerId]?.services || []).concat({
          serviceName: current.serviceName,
          start: current.start,
          end: current.end
        })
      }
    }),
    {}
  )
);
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    customerId: 1,
    customerName: "john",
    serviceName: "serviceName1",
    start: { dateTime: "15:00" },
    end: { dateTime: "16:00" }
  },
  {
    customerId: 2,
    customerName: "doe",
    serviceName: "serviceName2",
    start: { dateTime: "14:00" },
    end: { dateTime: "15:00" }
  },
  {
    customerId: 2,
    customerName: "doe",
    serviceName: "serviceName3",
    start: { dateTime: "12:00" },
    end: { dateTime: "13:00" }
  }
];

const processedData = Object.values(
  data.reduce(
    (dataObj, current) => ({
      ...dataObj,
      [current.customerId]: {
        ...dataObj[current.customerId],
        customerId: current.customerId,
        customerName: current.customerName,
        services: (dataObj[current.customerId]?.services || []).concat({
          serviceName: current.serviceName,
          start: current.start,
          end: current.end
        })
      }
    }),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(processedData);
```

Map the processed appointments data.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">room</th>
            <th scope="col">customer name</th>
            <th scope="col">serviceName1</th>
            <th scope="col">serviceName 2</th>
            <th scope="col">serviceName 3</th>
            <th scope="col">other</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {processedAppointments.map((appointments: any, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={appointments.customerId}>
                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{appointments.customerName}</td>
                {
                  appointments.services.map((service) => (
                    <td key={service.serviceName}>
                      {`${formatDateTime(service.start?.dateTime)} - ${formatDateTime(service.end?.dateTime)}`}
                    </td>
                  ))
                }
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
```

Since it seems you've only 3 service columns, if your data should happen to include more than that then you should slice what you need from the processed data. I.e. something like `appointments.services.slice(-3).map(...` to grab up to the last 3.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I have added index as key because in your case index is unique

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Table>
      <thead>
        <tr key="heading">
          <th scope="col">room</th>
          <th scope="col">customer name</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName1</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName 2</th>
          <th scope="col">serviceName 3</th>
          <th scope="col">other</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.appointments.map((appointments: any, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <td>{appointments.customerName}</td>
              <td>{`${formatDateTime(
                appointments.start?.dateTime
              )} - ${formatDateTime(appointments.end?.dateTime)}`}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
```

Comment: that is not what he wanted

Comment: @henk The key of element is always unique. So put it index as key because customer id is same as per data. and add customer id as ref={appointments.customerId} for another action.